# VB.NET vs C#: Anonymous types and intellisense

Tags: c#, vb.net, intellisense, anonymous-types

How come when do this in C#...

`var x = new { Name = "aaa" };`

...I can get intellisense on `.Name`, but when I do this in VB.NET...

`Dim x = New With {.Name = "aaa"}`

...I get no intellisene on `.Name`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question here.  In VB.NET, you have to use the module level `option infer on`.

I was going to just delete this question after I figured out the problem, but 1) I can't because this question already has an answer and 2) I am sure this will be helpful to others anyway.

Happy inferring.

Answer (score 6):

This sounds a momentary situation to me. Because when I try,

```
Dim x = New With {.Name = "aaa"}
```

It shows

[image]

Consider also [`Option Infer Statement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384665.aspx)

> Enables the use of local type inference in declaring variables.

Comment: Ah... the fact that this works for you prompted me to research module-level switches.  It appears you need to use `option infer on`.

Comment: @Soner, the OP's comment seems more helpful than a "works for me" answer. ;) You should consider incorporating [`option infer on`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384665.aspx) to your answer.

Comment: I am actually going to post it as an answer to my question when I get around to it.